# How to put constraints on a phone number in SQLite?

Tags: database, sqlite

I want to put a constraint on the attribute phoneNumber to only allow valid Dutch phone numbers. This code somehow results in a syntax error. What is wrong with it?

```
phoneNumber TEXT NOT NULL
    CHECK(phoneNumber LIKE '06[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]');
```

Comment: You need a comma between the column definition and the table constraint.

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite, you would do this with a regular expression, not `LIKE`:

```
CHECK (phoneNumber REGEXP '^06[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$');
```

I should emphasize though that SQLite recognizes `REGEXP`, but doesn't actually [implement the function](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> The `REGEXP` operator is a special syntax for the `regexp()` user
>   function. No `regexp()` user function is defined by default and so use
>   of the `REGEXP` operator will normally result in an error message. If an
>   application-defined SQL function named "regexp" is added at run-time,
>   then the `X REGEXP Y` operator will be implemented as a call to
>   `regexp(Y,X)`.

You will need to provide this function in order to use it in your logic.

Answer (score 0):

LIKE does not support character classes.
In SQLite, you can use [GLOB](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like) instead:

```
CREATE TABLE [...] (
    [...],
    phoneNumber TEXT NOT NULL
       CHECK(phoneNumber GLOB '06[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
);
```

(Please note that you need two closing parentheses, one for the CHECK, and one for the table's column list).